# Cutting users off in Windows console sessions

Tags: windows-server-2008, console

I'm currently working in a company where many of us log onto hosts/servers under Windows Server 2008 via console session.

If one person is logged on and another tries it causes the person who was logged on first (and maybe doing something important) to be cut off.

Is there such a thing as an application for such events where before logging on people can see if any other IP address is controlling the host/server?

Also, if the person on the console session had the ability to leave a note for anybody thinking of taking over the session of when they are finished etc..  I have many other ideas for such things but could someone tell me if such an application exists?

Comment: are they sharing the same credentials?

Comment: Ya.. Per say we all log on using the same username and password. We have applications running on it and scheduled tasks so dont want to log off ever!

Comment: seems you need multisession. I have not used rdp for along time but I assume you are using a Windows Server family not a desktop one (which does not support multisession for sure).

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you run the RDC client (mstsc.exe) using the `/admin` switch to remotely administer a Windows Server 2008 server that **has** Terminal Server installed.

At any point in time, there can be at most two active remote administration sessions, and this limit cannot be changed.

To be able to use these two sessions rather than one, and depending on your network architecture, you must disable one or both of the following :

- In the Local Group Policy Editor, in `Computer
  Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Terminal
  Services\Terminal Server\Connections`,  this setting is called
  `Restrict Terminal Services users to a single remote session`
- In Terminal Services Configuration, General section, Edit settings,
  this is called `Restrict each user to a single session`.

<sub>[(source)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947723)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you login to another machine on the same domain and use Terminal Services manager you can connect to another machine and see who is logged on to it, see how long they have been idle and if necessary kick them off.

Answer (score 0):

In Remote Desktop Session Host Configuration, set "Restrict each user to a single session" to No.

That assumes you are running Windows Server.  Windows desktop operating systems only allow one connected user at a time.